# Vue JS How to set option as selected based on passed nested v-for value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a nested v-for inside of another v-for in my Vue project. I'm successfully grabbing correct data; however, I'm trying to use a select dropdown to populate a field and automatically grab the selected option based on the value that would normally work fine in a text field.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
<tr v-for="review in reviews" v-bind:reviewLoc="review.reviewLocation">
  <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{review.id}}</td>
  <td><input class="form-control" v-model="review.reviewUser" placeholder="{{review.reviewUser}}"/></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" v-model="review.reviewBody" placeholder="{{review.reviewBody}}"/></td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control " v-model="reviewSelectedLocationName">
      <option v-for="(location, index) in locations" :value="location.locationName" :selected="location.id == review.reviewLocation" >
        {{location.locationName}}
      </option>
    </select></td>
  <td style="white-space: nowrap; text-align: right;"><button class="btn btn-info" type="button" @click="updateReview(review)"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger ml-1" type="button" @click="deleteReview(review.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

Specifically, my issues are with this loop.

```
 <option v-for="(location, index) in locations" :value="location.locationName" :selected="location.id == review.reviewLocation" >
   {{location.locationName}}
 </option>
```

As you can see, my goal is to populate to make the option selected by pulling from a list of {{{location.LocationName}}}} and comparing its value to the one at {{review.reviewLocation}}}

I thought basing selected=" on whether or not locationName was equal to reviewLocation would work, but I'm having no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, been stuck on this simple issue all day.

Comment: The idea of using a `selected` property on the `option` element does not translate well into Vue, instead, the `v-model` controls which of the `options` are selected based on the `value`. If you need to hydrate the value of `reviewSelectedLocationName` you should perform the assignment to that `v-model` in another area, such as a `watcher`, `mounted` lifecycle hook, or after an xhrrequest hydrates your data, or some combination of all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have set `v-model="reviewSelectedLocationName"` on your `<select>` tag, which dictates what option is selected. You could give each item in `reviews` a `selectedLocation` which is initially the same as the `reviewLocation`, and add `v-model="review.selectedLocation"` instead.